# Nhibernate .class equivalent in QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql, queryover

Below are HQL queries for specific type of classes

```
select a from Animal a
where TYPE(a) in ('Cat', 'Dog')
and a.sex = 'Male'
order by a.name


select a from Animal a
where a.class in ('Cat', 'Dog')
and a.sex = 'Male'
order by a.name
```

Im wondering is there and equivalent using QueryOver?

Comment: maybe there is but in the meantime you can always `.Where(Projections.eq("class", ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GetType` with the `IsIn` QueryOver extension method to accomplish this:

```
session.QueryOver<Animal>()
    .Where(a => a.GetType().IsIn(new[] { "Cat", "Dog" })
    /* .. etc */
```

You should use the discriminator values that your NHibernate mapping uses.

Comment: it didnt work btw the reason i want to do this is because i want to solve a problem stated in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491592/nhibernate-return-a-specific-type-of-union-subclass-in-a-queryover-with-join

Comment: Can you expand on "it didn't work?" What did the generated SQL look like? Did you get an error?

Comment: Sorry about that, basically what happen is i joined  TType1 to TType2 in a QueryOver is it cannot execute the query cannot resolve the type being joined.

Comment: my query is something like session.QueryOver<TType>().JoinAlias(x=> x.propertyoftypeTType2,...).Where(x=> x.propertyoftypeTType2.GetType().IsIn(..)

Comment: This works, but note that the `IsIn` array has to be the same type as the discriminator value in the database.  If the discriminator is a string, then the array must be a string.  If the discriminator is an int, then the array must be int.